# Rigify Rig is no longer editible

Tags: rigify

*background*

I made the mistake of saving my project in 2.8, this broke the project (crashes in 2.79). thus, I created a new project (2.79) and 'appended' the old project's data (text, texture, mesh, armature, action) via the 'file' menu.

*problem*

it appears that I can no longer pose the rig, it still animates via the actions I had (timeline scrub), but I can't grab individual (ik/fk) bones any longer (as if it were in object mode)

I noticed that the "bone groups" under the armature tab still contains color-coded groups to which bones are assigned, however the UI still shows them orange as if it were in object mode.

[image]

as opposed to the default rig
[image]

editx2: Interestingly, I was able to snap a mis-aligned frame which tells me the rig still contains its meta-data (or whatever it is), I just cant manually do it via the UI...
[image]
[image]

Comment: You won't have this problem if you'd just copy>paste the character with the rig from one file to another, although I never had problems with appending a character with any rig from another file. Different situation is with linking, then you would have to "Make single user" to edit the rig.

Comment: copy/pasting results in the same issue. I came to the conclusion the rig was actually truncated somehow (maybe it lost information when importing to 2.8 or something) after a few days of wasting time, I ended up just re-rigging/animating it :/